# iOS- Table row/cell behaviour when it has a details disclosure button?

Tags: ios

In my tableview I have a set number of rows and all have a detail disclosure button, clicking on detail disclosure button takes the user to a new view displaying info in a text view. I am not able to conclude on how the row should behave when user taps it because the Apple guidelines for table view and for detail disclosure button is confusing.

Please can anyone explain the below 2 scenarios for me. Thanks in advance.

1. Is it correct that the new view slides in only when the user taps the detail disclosure button and nothing happens when user taps elsewhere in the row.
2. What should be the behaviour if the user taps on the detail disclosure button with regard to highlighting?
3. What should be the behaviour of the table row if user taps elsewhere in the row ?

Apple guidelines says "When a detail disclosure button appears in a table row, tapping elsewhere in the row does not activate the detail disclosure button; instead, it selects the row item or results in app-defined behavior."

and Apple table view guidelines says "A table row highlights briefly when the user taps a selectable item. If a row selection results in navigation to a new screen, the selected row highlights briefly as the new screen slides into place. When the user navigates back to the previous screen, the originally selected row again highlights briefly to remind the user of their earlier selection (it does not remain highlighted)."

Answer (score 2):

When you tap on the row this delegate method is invoked:

```
– tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
```

When you tap on detail disclosure button the following delegate method is invoked:

```
– tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:
```

> **tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:**
>
> Tells the delegate that the user tapped the accessory (disclosure)
>   view associated with a given row.
>   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
>   Parameters
>
> tableView
>
> ```
> The table-view object informing the delegate of this event. indexPath
>
> An index path locating the row in tableView.
> ```
>
> Discussion
>
> The delegate usually responds to the tap on the disclosure button (the
>   accessory view) by displaying a new view related to the selected row.
>   This method is not called when an accessory view is set for the row at
>   indexPath. Availability
>
> ```
> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
> ```
>
> Declared In UITableView.h
>
> **tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:**
>
> Tells the delegate that the specified row is now selected.
>   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath Parameters
>
> tableView
>
> ```
> A table-view object informing the delegate about the new row selection.  indexPath
>
> An index path locating the new selected row in tableView.
> ```
>
> Discussion
>
> The delegate handles selections in this method. One of the things it
>   can do is exclusively assign the check-mark image
>   (UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) to one row in a section
>   (radio-list style). This method isn’t called when the editing property
>   of the table is set to YES (that is, the table view is in editing
>   mode). See "“Managing Selections”" in Table View Programming Guide
>   for iOS for further information (and code examples) related to this
>   method. Availability
>
> ```
> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
> ```
>
> See Also
>
> ```
> – tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:
> – tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:
> ```
>
> Declared In UITableView.h

Reference : [UITableViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have made the table row tap and detail disclosure button tap to do the same -> tap on row or on button now highlights the row and brings in a new view.

Answer (score 0):

You can do whatever you want with this discloure button. 1)New views can slide event if will tap  on row. 2) nothing 3) you can dot whatever you want: show new `UIViewController`, `UIAlertView` etc. It depends on your imagination. There are no restrictions for this.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have made the table row tap and detail disclosure button tap to do the same -> tap on row or on button now highlights the row and brings in a new view.